Is there any physical process producing a logistic distribution?
In his Logit Models, J.S. Cramer writes the following (p. 23)

Are there no physical processes producing a logistic distribution?

You may want to have a peek to Chapter 23 (Volume 2, Maximum Entropy) in David Blower's books. Blower credits Ed Jaynes for developing the logistic distribution from maximum entropy constraints. You may download his books as PFDs from www.BayesInAction.nl.

+1. But IMHO the comment is practically meaningless, because "physical processes" must be expressed quantitatively and the distribution depends on how one expresses the values.  For instance, it's perfectly valid to express p-values as log odds -- and under most null hypotheses, the log odds of the p-value have a logistic density.  That covers a lot of applications!

There are several ways how a logistic function can arrise in statistics. See: Deduce the logistic regression formula
Most of these ways describe a logistic regression model which is a binary distribution. One of them is a process that generates a logistic distribution:
The difference of two Gumbel distributed variables.
The Gumbel distribution itself arises in physical processes in a similar way as the Gaussian distribution. It is an approximation for a value that is derived from many multiple variables. The Gumbel distribution approximates a maximum of those variables, the Normal distribution approximates a sum or mean of those variables.
